# Remove sleep from Beep(), alternative method to produce sound?

Tags: c, audio

Consider the below program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Beep(220 * i, 250);
        printf("%d\n", 22o * i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This makes a sound for 250ms and prints the frequency of that sound. There's a delay between prints, however, due to it sleeping between beeps.

Conversely, doing something like `printf("\a");` instead doesn't have a sleep between beeps. I know it's not entirely equivalent to `Beep()`, as you can't modulate the sound or alter duration, but what I'm interested in is the zero sleep between sounds.

I want to use `Beep()` with sounds of 250ms duration, but I don't want the program to sleep between them. I have a particle simulator that produces a sound with `Beep()` when a collision happens, but while the sound is playing the simulation halts for the duration. I want it to make a 250ms beep but no sleep involved.

What are my options?

edit; [here's a video showing the pause in my simulator.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoWD6j5HN-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of playing the sound in the main thread,
instantiate a thread for playing the beep.

then let the thread kill it self when the beep has played.

[Here](http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/threads/threads.c.php) is a tutorial for creating a thread:

this code has been taken from the tutorial, and then modifed to your needs:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* This is our thread function.  It is like main(), but for a thread*/
void *threadFunc(void *arg)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Beep(220 * i, 250);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t pth;  // this is our thread identifier
    int i = 0;


    pthread_create(&pth,NULL,threadFunc,"foo");
    printf("%d\n", 22o * i);

    while(i < 100)
    {
        usleep(1);
        printf("simulation continues...\n");
        ++i;
    }

    printf("main waiting for thread to terminate...\n");
    pthread_join(pth,NULL);

    return 0;
}
```